# What is the difference between onClick={onRouteChange('home')} and onClick={ () => onRouteChange('home')}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
onClick={onRouteChange('home')}
onClick={ () => onRouteChange('home')}
```

from the tutorials I've been watching, it says that the first one will be called when it's rendered while the latter will run whenever onClick happens. I quite don't get it.

Comment: The first one will be call when your view is rendering, when the second will be called when a user click on your element, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062552/how-do-i-call-a-method-within-another-method-in-react-class-es6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events such as `onClick`, `onBlur`, etc must be assigned a function (aka callback). That function will be exectured when the related event is fired. In other words, it must be assigned a function which contains the code to be executed when that event occurs.

This means that:

- `onClick={onRouteChange('home')}`

  this assigns the return value of `onRouteChange('home')` to the `click` event. If that function **returns** a function, then you're all good. But I am guessing this isn't the case.

  ---
- `onClick={() => onRouteChange('home')}`

  This assigns an anonymous function (which is the `() =>` part), which when run, invokes the `onRouteChange` function. This is probably what you want.

---

So if  your function is something like:

```
onRouteChange(path) {
  this.props.history.push(path);
}
```

Then you want the last solution.

However, if it is more like:

```
onRouteChange(path) {
  return () => {
    this.props.history.push(path);
  };
}
```

then the first solution would work.

Comment: Thank you so much! So in other words, the first one will be called immediately and will assign the return value to the onClick() event. While the latter will return a function which I wanted to be. THANKS!